# Remove light blue border when mouseover textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox

For a textbox, when I mouse over it there is this light blue border appearing, any idea how to remove that?

Comment: Probably all similar programs in your environment work identically -- why would you defeat this behavior and potentially confuse your users, who might be used to it from other applications?

Answer (score 6):

You can modify the `Template`, this would be the minimum without any borders at all:

```
  <TextBox>
    <TextBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <ScrollViewer Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </TextBox.Template>
  </TextBox>
```